# jQuery validation with two buttons

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello and thank you for help.

I have problem with validation.

Basically I have one form with two buttons.

One button need to validate whole form and second only fields with class ".number".

I tried something like this:

```
$('.save_draft').click(function(){
    $('form').validate({
      rules: {
        field: {
          required: true,
          number: true
        }
      }
    });
});

$('.submit_form').click(function(){
    $('form').validate().form();
});
```

But it's actually didn't work for me.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to re-valdiate the whole form and present messages, etc.

```
$('.submit_form').click(function(){
    $('form .number').valid();
});
```

Though, if you set it up initially, it should already be operating on the `submit` event, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('form').validate({
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        number: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Basically my problem is if I click on .submit_form or ether .save_draft it validates all the form with all the fields. But I need on .submit_form validate all form and on .save_draft validate only fields with class number. $('form').valid(); not working for me as well :( I'm stuck.

Comment: @surmanto - All, I see what you mean, do this: `$('form .number').valid();`

Comment: @surmanto - You should set up `.validate()` externally, before the buttons are clicked, do you have a link to a sample page?